# choose file, change filesize, upload to php and send by phpmailer

Tags: html, canvas, phpmailer, image-resizing, forms, http-post

I want to include input type="text" and input type "file" to one form. The files (multiple) needs to get resized at client-side before upload to server.
On PHP I want to e-mail the resized-files and the input text by phpmailer.

There´s a manual for HTML5 resize by Canvas: https://www.codeforest.net/html5-image-upload-resize-and-crop

I tried successfully to upload client-side resized graphics to server.
This works fantastic with uploadResized.php

```
if ($_POST) {
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'uploads/');
$img = $_POST['image'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.jpg';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
}
```

I don´t unterstand why there´s a second php-file (upload.php) mentioned in HTML?

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php">
```

My question is:
How to overtake both (Text and resized Files) at PHP in a way, I can resend by phpmailer? And what will be the code-snipped?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Have you actually tried? The example in the PHPMailer readme shows how to attach a file.

Comment: Yes my actual working setup is a form with text and fileupload to php with phpformmailer. But I have big problems by this resize process. I don't know how to pick the dataurl to phpmailer.

Comment: You've already got code for decoding the image data and saving it to a file; all you need to to is give that path you saved it to to PHPMailer using `addAttachment($file)`.

Comment: Ok noted, do you know why there're 2 .php Files? I also don't understand why uploadResized.php is loading file to server directly after choosing file without push button upload. So may it's caused by asynchron upload? What's the code in upload.php to pick file?

Comment: The URL in the action of your form determines where the form will submit to. If you're bypassing that using JS, then it doesn't matter, but you could probably set it to also point at `uploadResized.php`, or leave it empty (which means it will submit to its own URL). You'd need to refer to uploadResized's docs.

Comment: I will take uploadresizes.php to form-tag and xhr.open. In PHP-Code I will try with addAttachment($file). Is there any think I have to keep in mind for multiple files?

Comment: So I used `uploadResized.php` in the form-action attribute and in `xhr.open('POST', 'uploadResized.php', true);`. So now the file get uploaded directly by coosing image. When I push the Upload Button, the input text contents are send to server and also a second picture file. Server stores a 0KB image to upload dir and reply with storing error. So my Problem is I don´t know how to pick file of first asyncron upload at serverside with input text contents and send to phpmailer. Any ideas?